# Удаление последнего элемента в списке

Tags: c++, list

Прошу не ругать если я что-то не так объяснил, мне 15 лет. Я увлекаюсь программированием на языке С++. В настоящее время я решил немного подтянуть свои знание в структурировании данных. Я часто сталкивался с проблемой каталогизации большого количества однотипных данных, я не люблю подключать инструменты со сторонних библиотек по типу STL, я считаю что использование сторонних библиотек только мешает в процессе обучения.

Я решил написать свой класс для структурирования однотипных данных, я вдохновился "list<>" классом из STL. Я посмотрел некоторые исходники и мне стало интересно почему момент удаления последнего элемента из списка реализован таким образом:

```
template< typename T >
bool list< T >::remove() {
    if (m_head) {
        Node* n_head = m_head->m_next;
        delete m_head;
        m_head = n_head;
    }
}
```

Я поверхностно понимаю устройство памяти и работу с ней на данном языке, но не могу понять почему в этом примере используется оператор delete[].

Разве это не правильней реализовать немного другим способом? Например так:

```
template< typename T >
bool list< T >::remove() {
    if (m_head) {
        m_head = m_head->m_next;
    }
}
```

Сначала мне казалось что область памяти под список просто очиститься и перевыделиться под новую структуру. Я не совсем в этом уверен и не очень понимаю как это правильно отследить. Прошу помочь мне с этим моментом. Прошу не писать что я маленький дурак в ответах, это и так понятно :)

Структура "Node":

```
struct Node {
    Node() : m_next(NULL) { }
    Node(const T& value) : m_value(value), m_next(NULL) { }

    T m_value;
    Node* m_next;
};
```

Comment: Если объект класса `Node`, на который указывает указатель `m_head`, был создан посредством вызова оператора `new` но не будет удален посредством вызова оператора `delete`, то будет утечка памяти. А еще не стоит путать `delete` (удаление одного объекта) и `delete[]` (удаление массива объектов).

Comment: У меня это реализовано вот так:

`Node * node = new Node(value);
node->m_next = m_head;
m_head = node;`

Я не вызываю оператор `new` непосредственно к `m_next`, это может привести к утечке памяти? В любом случае спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на очень интересную мысль по поводу реализации ещё нескольких функций.

Comment: Вы уверены. что смотрите правильный (верно работающий) чужой код, фрагмент которого приводите?

Comment: Кажется весяма логично, что метод remove что-то удаляет, а не просто переставляет ссылки. Почему используют `delete[]`, а не просто `delete` сложно сказать без остального кода. P.s. Более поучительный и красивый в плане реализазии список - двусвязный кольцевой с фиктивной нулевой вершиной. Поучительно, ибо нужно наследование. Красиво, ибо итераторы реализовываются без шаманства.

Comment: "*я не люблю подключать инструменты со сторонних библиотек по типу STL*" - это никак не сторонняя библиотека, это *стандартная библиотека C++*.

Comment: В дополнение коммента Harry: вы наверно путаете C и C++, когда говорите, что stl - сторонняя библиотека. В любом случае, раз вы так заинтересованы в обучении, советую начать с изучения C.

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на исходник, а то я что-то не вижу у [листа](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) метода `bool list<T>::remove()`

Comment: Простите, возможно я изначально неверно задал вопрос. На данный момент меня интересует только момент который связанный с утечкой памяти. По поводу _сторонних библиотек_ я немного некорректно выразился, я не люблю подключать библиотеки вообще. Совет с изучением `C` мне показался немного абсурдным, я хочу изучать _ООП_, а обычный `C` с этим никак не связан. Вот ссылка на ресурс с которого я подсматривал код: http://itnotesblog.ru/note.php?id=178

Comment: @xm1r10n, в коде по ссылке 1) удаляют **первый** (а не последний) элемент списка; 2) используют `delete` (а не `delete[]`)  / Там все верно, откуда ваши примеры, не понятно. /  Кстати, *серьезные люди* все же предпочитают Си (и работают со списками [вот так](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h))

Comment: Никогда не понимал логику людей которые на вопрос о конкретном языке пытаются придраться к словам, а после советуют изучать другой язык... Я задал конкретный вопрос, а мне ответили ссылкой на реализацию данного момента на другом языке. Я понимаю `C` и `C++` языки не далеки друг от друга, но меня интересует реализация со стороны ООП, я написал это выше. 

Опять же, я повторю свой вопрос: В предложенном мною варианте случится утечка памяти? Код который я использовал для обучения я уже использовал, он 100% рабочий. Мне просто показалось что некоторые моменты неправильно реализованы

Comment: @xm1r10n, утечка будет. Если узел создается с помощью `new`, то и удалять его нужно с помощью `delete`.

Comment: @xm1r10n, к слову, ООП можно успешно применять и в C.

Comment: Что за люди на этом борде) Вы тут всех агитируете изучать `C` в топиках о `C++`? Зачем этот мой `C++` вообще нужен?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> мне казалось что область памяти под список просто очиститься и перевыделиться

Объект, который создали с помощью `new`, существует ровно до вызова на нем `delete`. Сам он не удалится.

---

Вот если бы вы использовали вместо обычного указателя умный (`std::unique_ptr`, ну или `std::shared_ptr`), тогда ваш вариант бы сработал (в случае `std::unique_ptr` - с небольшими изменениями). В этом случае умный указатель сам вызвал бы `delete`, на то он и умный.

Comment: Спасибо, но опять же, я не вызываю `new` в своём примере. Я так понимаю что утечка памяти произойти не должна?

Comment: @xm1r10n Вы же в комментах сказали, что вызываете. *"У меня это реализовано вот так: `Node * node = new Node(value); node->m_next = m_head; m_head = node;`"*.

Comment: А, понял! Спасибо! Я немного не разбираюсь в некоторых моментах, спасибо за терпеливость моей неграмотности!